# Access Denied in Jquery for the file client.json from amazonaws.com

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress

This is a wired error message on my HTML page. It is a WordPress page and I am getting this error for some particular pages. Most of the pages are working fine but in some of my pages following error message is coming. I have checked everything and found everything fine.

Any idea why this error is generating from jquery?

**"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mfesecure-public/host/localhost/client.json"client.json**

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The error is not related to jQuery.

Check if the file exists on the S3 bucket and has read permission to everyone or make it public.

Comment: I don't have S3 bucket, using the jquery file only. And most importantly I am not calling that file from anywhere of my codes. I guess jquery is calling that file automatically!

Comment: The url http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mfesecure-public/host/localhost/client.json is for S3. How do you upload thr file? And cany you access it?

Comment: This is the mystery! I don't upload anything and also I can't access that file!

Answer (score 0):

In my site, request was from McAfee script 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0p9L.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as image... it's not useful at all, please edit your post and put the code as text...